# Allow remote access to Oracle 12c (listener failed)

Tags: oracle, remote-access, oracle12c

After finish the installation of Oracle 12c on Centos 7, now I try to allow access on my PC (via SQL Delopper) to the server. But the probleme is that when I do:

```
lsnrctl status
```

I get this error:

```
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

So, I try to start the listener with:

```
lsnrctl start
```

And I get this error:

```
TNS-01198: Listener failed to initialize valid node list
 NL-07007: internal error
  NL-00408: cannot find or read value
   NL-00408: cannot find or read value
    NL-00408: cannot find or read value
```

To finish I go to this website: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ORA/TNS-01198%3A+Listener+failed+to+initialize+valid+node+list+post+upgrade+from+11g+to+12c

Then I added, as he tell the following line on the listener.ora file

```
VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_<LISTENER_SERVICENAME> = OFF
```

but nothing change.

**To finish, this is my listener.ora file:**

```
#listener.ora Network Configuration File: /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora

#Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_<LISTENER_SID> = OFF


LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =  84.254.25.9)(PORT = 1521))

      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Look at that article again; you shouldn't have left the `<>` characters in the setting name. Not sure about the SID part; you might need `VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_LISTENER=OFF` (looking at doc ID 1969856.1).

Comment: Ohw!! Thanks you I added the line you give me and the listener start succesfully :D

Comment: So, now what can I do to access on my PC to the database with SQL Developper ?

Comment: read the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_connecting.htm#TDDDG12200